# Rosserial missing subscribed messages

Tags: ros, rosserial, publisher, dynamixel, servo

I'm making a humanoid robot kid size and ros noetic to control several dynamixel MX28-AT. I have a code to receive angles calculated in the high level using rosserial to connect with teensy4.0 at 1000000 of baudrate. I'm having some problems when i increase frequency of my publisher(above 2hz). I put a led in callback function to debbug since, everytime an angles is published, the led will turn on. The thing is: i noticed that, at higher frequencies, the led sometimed didn't turn on even though the angles was being published (i checked using `rostopic echo servo`, being servo the name of my topic). This is disturbing the servo movements, since sometimes the data doesn't get to it. How can i improve this connection?
This is the code in teensy4.0:

```
#include <Dynamixel2Arduino.h>

#include <Wire.h>
#include "SparkFun_BNO080_Arduino_Library.h"

#include <ros.h>
#include <ros/time.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16MultiArray.h>
#include <std_msgs/Header.h> 
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Quaternion.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Vector3.h>

#define BROADCAST_ID 254
#define DXL_SERIAL1 Serial1
#define DXL_SERIAL2 Serial2
#define DXL_SERIAL3 Serial3
#define DXL_SERIAL5 Serial5
#define blinkPin 13

const int DXL_DIR_PIN1 = 2; // pino de controle Serial1
const int DXL_DIR_PIN2 = 9; // pino de controle Serial2
const int DXL_DIR_PIN3 = 23; // pino de controle Serial3
const int DXL_DIR_PIN5 = 22; // pino de controle Serial5

Dynamixel2Arduino dxl1(DXL_SERIAL1, DXL_DIR_PIN1); //Perna direita
Dynamixel2Arduino dxl2(DXL_SERIAL2, DXL_DIR_PIN2); //Perna esquerda
Dynamixel2Arduino dxl3(DXL_SERIAL3, DXL_DIR_PIN3); //Perna esquerda
Dynamixel2Arduino dxl5(DXL_SERIAL5, DXL_DIR_PIN5); //Perna direita

BNO080 myIMU;

#define LEG_ID 6 //this variable was created only to be used in for.
#define RIGHT_ID 6 //this variable was created only to be used in for.
#define RIGHT_ID_TEMPORARIO 6 
#define LEFT_ID 12 //this variable was created only to be used in for.
#define DXL_ID_CNT 12
#define DXL_ID_CNT_TEMPORARIO 12
uint8_t LEGS_ID[DXL_ID_CNT] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
uint8_t LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[DXL_ID_CNT] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7};
uint8_t RIGHT_LEG_ID[DXL_ID_CNT] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
uint8_t LEFT_LEG_ID[DXL_ID_CNT] = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
uint8_t right_leg[DXL_ID_CNT] = {180, 88, 180, 200, 202, 72};
uint8_t left_leg[DXL_ID_CNT] = {180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180};
uint8_t legs[DXL_ID_CNT] = {180, 88, 180, 200, 202, 72, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180};
uint8_t legs_temporario[DXL_ID_CNT] =         {75, 160, 180, 180, 90, 180,    180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 140};
uint8_t legs_initial_temporario[DXL_ID_CNT] = {75, 160, 180, 180, 90, 180,    180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 140};
uint8_t legs_initial[DXL_ID_CNT] = {180, 88, 180, 200, 202, 72, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180};

using namespace ControlTableItem;

ros::NodeHandle nh;

//IMU ros config
sensor_msgs::Imu inertial;
geometry_msgs::Vector3 lin;
geometry_msgs::Vector3 ang;
ros::Publisher pub("micro/IMU", &inertial);
char in[] = "/imu";

bool going = LOW;

void servo_cb(const std_msgs::Int16MultiArray& cmd_msg){
  digitalWrite(blinkPin, going);
  going = !going;
  dxl2.setGoalPosition(12, 180 + cmd_msg.data[6] , UNIT_DEGREE);
  dxl1.setGoalPosition(11, 180 + cmd_msg.data[7] , UNIT_DEGREE);
  dxl3.setGoalPosition(10, 180 + cmd_msg.data[8] , UNIT_DEGREE);
  dxl5.setGoalPosition(9, 180 + cmd_msg.data[9] , UNIT_DEGREE);
  //for(int i = 0; i < DXL_ID_CNT; i++){
    //legs_temporario[i] = legs_initial_temporario[i] + cmd_msg.data[i];
  //}
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int16MultiArray> sub("servo", servo_cb);

// Position PID Gains
// Adjust these gains to tune the behavior of DYNAMIXEL
uint16_t position_p_gain = 40;
uint16_t position_i_gain = 10;
uint16_t position_d_gain = 1;

void setup() {
  digitalWrite(blinkPin, LOW);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);

  //bno_setup();//BNO setup

  Serial.begin(1000000);
    
  dxl1.begin(1000000);
  dxl2.begin(1000000);
  dxl3.begin(1000000);
  dxl5.begin(1000000);

  dxl1.setPortProtocolVersion(1.0);
  dxl2.setPortProtocolVersion(1.0);
  dxl3.setPortProtocolVersion(1.0);
  dxl5.setPortProtocolVersion(1.0);

  // Set Position PID Gains(Serial 1)
  dxl1.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_P_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_p_gain);
  dxl1.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_I_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_i_gain);
  dxl1.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_D_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_d_gain);
  

  // Set Position PID Gains(Serial 2)
  dxl2.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_P_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_p_gain);
  dxl2.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_I_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_i_gain);
  dxl2.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_D_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_d_gain);
  dxl2.writeControlTableItem(RETURN_DELAY_TIME, 12, 0);
  dxl2.writeControlTableItem(STATUS_RETURN_LEVEL, 12, 1);
  

  // Set Position PID Gains(Serial 3)
  dxl3.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_P_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_p_gain);
  dxl3.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_I_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_i_gain);
  dxl3.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_D_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_d_gain);
  

  // Set Position PID Gains(Serial 5)
  dxl5.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_P_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_p_gain);
  dxl5.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_I_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_i_gain);
  dxl5.writeControlTableItem(POSITION_D_GAIN, BROADCAST_ID, position_d_gain);
  

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        dxl1.writeControlTableItem(STATUS_RETURN_LEVEL, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 1);
        dxl1.writeControlTableItem(MOVING_SPEED, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 80);
        dxl1.setGoalPosition(LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], legs_initial_temporario[i], UNIT_DEGREE);
//        dxl1.setGoalPosition(1, 20, UNIT_DEGREE);
        delay(1);
//      dxl1.setGoalPosition(1, 30, UNIT_DEGREE);
    }

    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++){
      dxl3.writeControlTableItem(MOVING_SPEED, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 80);
      dxl3.setGoalPosition(LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], legs_initial_temporario[i], UNIT_DEGREE);
//      dxl.setGoalPosition(12, 180, UNIT_DEGREE);
      delay(1);
//    dxl2.setGoalPosition(1, 20, UNIT_DEGREE);
//    delay(100);
//    dxl2.setGoalPosition(1, 30, UNIT_DEGREE);
    }

    for(int i = 6; i < 7; i++){
      //dxl2.writeControlTableItem(RETURN_DELAY_TIME, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 5);
    //  dxl2.writeControlTableItem(STATUS_RETURN_LEVEL, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 1);
     // dxl2.writeControlTableItem(MOVING_SPEED, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 80);
      dxl2.setGoalPosition(LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], legs_initial_temporario[i], UNIT_DEGREE);
//      dxl.setGoalPosition(12, 180, UNIT_DEGREE);
      delay(1); 
      }

    for(int i = 9; i < 12; i++){
      dxl5.writeControlTableItem(MOVING_SPEED, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 80);
      dxl5.setGoalPosition(LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], legs_initial_temporario[i], UNIT_DEGREE);
//      dxl.setGoalPosition(12, 180, UNIT_DEGREE);
      delay(1);
    }
    delay(6000);
}

void loop() {
  nh.spinOnce();
  //bno_loop(); //bno loop
  /*
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        dxl1.writeControlTableItem(MOVING_SPEED, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 0);
        dxl1.setGoalPosition(LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], legs_temporario[i], UNIT_DEGREE);
        
//        dxl1.setGoalPosition(1, 20, UNIT_DEGREE);
       // delay(1);
//      dxl1.setGoalPosition(1, 30, UNIT_DEGREE);
    }

    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++){
      dxl3.writeControlTableItem(MOVING_SPEED, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 0);
      dxl3.setGoalPosition(LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], legs_temporario[i], UNIT_DEGREE);
      
//      dxl.setGoalPosition(12, 180, UNIT_DEGREE);
    //  delay(1);
//    dxl2.setGoalPosition(1, 20, UNIT_DEGREE);
//    delay(100);
//    dxl2.setGoalPosition(1, 30, UNIT_DEGREE);
    }

    for(int i = 6; i < 7; i++){
//      dxl2.writeControlTableItem(MOVING_SPEED, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 0);
//      dxl2.setGoalPosition(LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], legs_temporario[i], UNIT_DEGREE);
      
      
//      dxl.setGoalPosition(12, 180, UNIT_DEGREE);
     // delay(1); 
      }

    for(int i = 9; i < 12; i++){
      dxl5.writeControlTableItem(MOVING_SPEED, LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], 0);
      dxl5.setGoalPosition(LEGS_ID_TEMPORARIO[i], legs_temporario[i], UNIT_DEGREE);
      
//      dxl.setGoalPosition(12, 180, UNIT_DEGREE);
    //  delay(1);
    }
 */   
}

void bno_setup(){
    pinMode(blinkPin, OUTPUT);
    Wire.begin();
    digitalWrite(blinkPin, LOW);
    if (myIMU.begin() == false)
    {
        digitalWrite(blinkPin, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(blinkPin, LOW);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(blinkPin, HIGH);
        while (1)
            ;
    }
    delay(10);
    Wire.setClock(400000); // Increase I2C data rate to 400kHz
    delay(10);
    myIMU.enableLinearAccelerometer(8); // m/s^2 no gravity
    myIMU.enableRotationVector(4);      // quat
    myIMU.enableGyro(12);               // rad/s

    nh.advertise(pub);

}

void bno_loop(){
    inertial.header.frame_id = in;
    inertial.header.stamp = nh.now();
    if (myIMU.dataAvailable() == true)
    {
        
        // internal copies of the IMU data
        byte linAccuracy = 0;
        byte gyroAccuracy = 0;
        float quatRadianAccuracy = 0;
        byte quatAccuracy = 0;

        // get IMU data in one go for each sensor type
        myIMU.getLinAccel(lin.x, lin.y, lin.z, linAccuracy);
        myIMU.getGyro(ang.x, ang.y, ang.z, gyroAccuracy);
        myIMU.getQuat(inertial.orientation.x, inertial.orientation.y, inertial.orientation.z, inertial.orientation.w, quatRadianAccuracy, quatAccuracy);
        inertial.angular_velocity = ang;
        inertial.linear_acceleration = lin;
        pub.publish(&inertial);
//        digitalWrite(blinkPin, LOW);
    }
    pub.publish(&inertial);
    delay(1);
}
```

This is the publisher sending 0 and 20 degrees to one servo, which is id 2, connected to serial2:

````
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int16MultiArray

going = True

def talker(angles):
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/servo', Int16MultiArray, queue_size=10)
    # If the motor has reached its limit, publish a new command.
    pub.publish(angles)

if _name_ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('teste_dimitria', anonymous=True)
    angles = Int16MultiArray()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            if going:
                angles.data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            else:
                angles.data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            talker(angles)
            going = not going  # Inverte o valor de 'going' a cada iteração
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
            pass
        rospy.Rate(50).sleep()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Just as test, I would move the publisher creation out of 'talker'. The creation of the publisher requires that other nodes be made aware of it's existance and if you create it, publish on it, and it disappears when the function exits, it's fully possible the subscriber missed the whole thing.

Create the publisher in main, and you can pass the handle to 'talker'.

Comment: Lucas: Also, the rospy.Rate(50) object should be created before you enter the while loop, then call its sleep() method when you need it.